# nftables filter port scan

Tags: centos, nftables

In order to ease my pain filtering dropped packets from logs I figured I'll filter out port scans "first" and log them separately.

However I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do that with nft. There's plenty on iptables, but the nft wiki seems to indicate a direct translation not possible?

Also, their examples while show how to match, don't show how to update the hashsets.

https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Moving_from_ipset_to_nftables

Any suggestions on how to filter portscans with nft? Other than using a 3rd party like fail2ban (that's the backup plan)

(System is centos 8 server, CLI)

Comment: as an update, I am currently experimenting with idea from here: https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg59088.html and their wiki here https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Updating_sets_from_the_packet_path actually suggests the contrary of what seems to be suggested on the moving from iptables link I originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link from @ciuly here is an extended version with IPv6 and IPv4 support. Requires Linux kernel >= 5.5

```bash
table ip block_tcp_portscan {
    set enemies {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags timeout
        timeout 5m
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        ip saddr @enemies update @enemies { ip saddr }
        tcp dport { 1-21, 23-24, 26-79 } update @enemies { ip saddr }
        ip saddr @enemies log drop
    }
}
table ip6 block_tcp_portscan_v6 {
    set enemies {
        type ipv6_addr
        flags timeout
        timeout 5m
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        ip6 saddr @enemies update @enemies { ip6 saddr }
        tcp dport { 1-21, 23-24, 26-79 } update @enemies { ip6 saddr }
        ip6 saddr @enemies log drop
    }
}
```